# Setup repository for pulling from GitHub but pushing to Company

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to setup a repository so that I can pull both from `GitHub` and a company internal repository but `push` (by default) only to the internal one and I'm confused about the proper steps I should take.

It looks like there are two approaches:

1. You would create the internal repository, clone it, add another remove (with an alias) and then merge from `GitHub` by using `--allow-unrelated-histories` (will it require me to always use this switch or is it a one-time sync?)
2. You would clone the `GitHub` repository and add a new upstream remote pointing to the internal repo that I would then use for `push`ing.

---

- Which setup would be a better one?
- Are there any signifficant dis/advantages of either one?
- Or maybe there is yet another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second option is more correct.

- Clone the Repository from Github and this branch will be automatically set as `origin` branch.
- Add the Internal remote branch as upstream by command:
  `git remote add upstream <url_of_repo>`

When pulling do this:

`git pull origin <branch-name>`

while pushing do this:

`git push upstream <branch-name>`

This the normal git flow and I don't think there will be any disadvantages of this flow.

I hope it helps!

Comment: I also had the feeling that the 2nd approach might be actually better. Just one more question: will it allow me to `pull` from the internal repo too or will I now here have to use the `--allow-unrelated-histories` switch? Or I'll just try it out...

Comment: I think you have to enable this flag for combining two separate unrelated Git repositories into one with a single history timeline.

Comment: I tried this approach and you end up with `--allow-unrelated-histories` in the other repository. It looks like there is no other way around. As soon as you try to `pull` the new remote, it'll tell you that histories are unrelated.